# Windows XP is logging slow in domain

Tags: windows-xp

My office machine has starting to take long time to boot up. I don't know whether I did something wrong because till last week it was working like a charm.
I am running windows XP connected with domain on Windows 2003 server.

Comment: Anyone else notice XP slowing down more and more in general since Vista came out?  My friends and i jokingly refer to it as MS's "'Upgrade to Vista' patch".  :)

Answer (score 3):

Try to set your domain server IP as default gateway and primary DNS on your workstation

Comment: unbelievable. Now my machine is logging in a flash! Thanks

Comment: That's a pretty big assumption that the domain server is also running DNS, isn't it?

Comment: No, it's a pretty reasonable assumption.